# (python)What is the role of 'i=i+1' among the While function?

Tags: python

If there is no 'i=i+1', the turtle repeats infinitely.
Please describe role of 'i=i+1' in relation to it.

```
import turtle
t=turtle.Turtle()
t.shape('turtle')
i=0
while i<=4:
    t.fd(50)
    t.rt(144)
    i=i+1
```

Comment: Add `print(i)` inside the `while` and see the magic :)

Comment: although the question is extremely basic, I would think the community could be a little more tolerant. The negative votes seem off putting.

Comment: `i=i+1` allows the code to get out of the `i <= 4` requirement in the while loop.

Answer (score 3):

Your intuition is right, without `i=i+1` the loop will execute indefinitely.

Essentially, `while` is a keyword which starts a loop. Any loop in a programming language consists of the following basic elements:

- loop variable (here, i)
- loop condition  or exit condition or repeat until (here, i<=4)
- job/set of instructions to perform/repeat inside the loop

now, if `i=i+1` is not there, your loop condition is always true, and hence, it will execute indefinitely. Since, we want the task to repeat 5 times (i is in range 0-4), we need to increment the value of i with the statement `i=i+1` everytime the loop has executed the set of statements.

PS: You might want to refer to a beginners introduction to some programming resource.

Answer (score 0):

"i" have the role of the counter in this example.
Every time the loop is executed it adds one to "i". If the "i" reach 4 the while loop wont be executed any more.
For the easiness to read this code instead of "i" you could name this variable "counter".

Answer (score 0):

```
i=i+1 #this is an increment operator that equals to i++ in other languages like C.
```

As same as,

```
i+= 1 #this is similar  to the above.
```

Example,

```
i = 0
while i<5:
    print(i)
    i+=1 (or) i= i+1
```

Answer (score 0):

It is cristal clear from the code:

```
i=0 # initially i is 0
while i<=4: # while i is less than or equal 4 continue looping
    t.fd(50)
    t.rt(144)
    i=i+1 # you increment to reach 5 at some point and stop 
          #otherwise, `i` will stay at 0 and therefore `i<=4` condition will always be true
```

Without `i=i+1` the code is exactly like this:

```
import turtle
t=turtle.Turtle()
t.shape('turtle')
i=0
while True:
    t.fd(50)
    t.rt(144)
```